# I want to add current datetime for a image which is taken from camera API using phonegap

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova, html5-canvas

I am developing an app for ios/andorid/windows, which have a functionality to capture image and save it in our apps. 
My Images are capturing and save to a folder and display in a div. But i want to add date time for that image which i am taken. lets say if take a image on 25-08-2013. I want to display this date time in the image at right corner.

How do we achieve this in phonegap. I heard about some canvas html5 feature but i am dont know how to use the taken image in canvas tag.

```
function capturePhoto() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
      destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI });
 }

function onFail(message) {
      alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}

function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
  console.log("Image Property-->");

  var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

  smallImage.style.display = 'block';

 // smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
  smallImage.src = imageData;
}

<div data-role="page">

<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <h1>DATE !T</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">
    <button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button><br>
    <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
    <h4>Footer</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do that using c# by this code

```
 FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\myImage.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);//or .jpg, etc...
        Image image = Image.FromStream(fs);
        fs.Close();

        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(image);
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(b);
        var date = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now);
        graphics.DrawString(date, this.Font, Brushes.Black, image.Width - (date.Length*5), 0);

        b.Save(@"c:\myImage.jpg", image.RawFormat);

        image.Dispose();
        b.Dispose();
```

if this dose not help inform me to search other method

Comment: I am developing application in phonegap that's need to support multi platform. Not only in c#.